# How to store output of MySQL command into a java variable (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was wondering how to issue a MySQL command that checks if a table within my database is empty and then subsequently store the boolean result into a java variable. I am trying to use JDBC commands to do this. 
This is what I have so far but it is not working properly:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty(Connection connection) {
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Boolean var = true;

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        System.out.println(statement.execute("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Persons) AS OUTPUT"));

        if(statement.execute("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Persons)")) {
            var = false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return var;
}
```

When I run the program with a completely new, unpopulated mySQL table, the function returns true. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Please read the javadoc for [`Statement.execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)). The boolean return value does not mean what you think it does. Tip: a `select` **always** returns a result set (or throws an exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test checks if the table exists, instead you want to see if the table contains any rows. In order to do so, select the count of rows from the table and verify it is greater than `0`. Prefer [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) over `Statement` (it's more efficient and performant), and you need a `ResultSet` to actually iterate the result from the server. Something like,

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty(Connection connection) {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    boolean res = false; // no need for the wrapper type here.

    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persons";
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        System.out.println(sql);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            res = resultSet.getInt(1) > 0;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Changed `var` to `res` because (as of Java 10) `var` is now a keyword in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As you are executing a select statement, instead of using [`Statement.execute(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)), you should use [`Statement.executeQuery(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) and iterate over its result set.

The boolean return value from `execute(..)` indicates if the first value is a result set or not. It is not the boolean column from your query. You should normally only use `execute(..)` if you don't know what type of statement it is, or if it is a statement that can produce multiple results (update counts and result sets).

So, instead use:

```
boolean exists;
try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Persons)")) {
    exists = rs.next() && rs.getBoolean(1);
}
```